# WF4 Persistance Small Examples

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I want to use the supported WF4 persistence for my WF4 Host, but I haven't seen any good, simple, concise examples to date.  I was hoping someone could come up with a sample, or knows of a site that has these types of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your SQL server management studio and make the persistence database.

For .Net 4.5
Use the SQL scripts at: %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en 
**SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema.sql** and **SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreLogic.sql** in that order.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlos/archive/2013/01/10/workflow-foundation-sql-scripts.aspx

Then Open Visual Studion and make a workflow and attach it to a  WorkflowApplication

```
_workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new International(), inParams);
```

where International is the name of a workflow ( a XAML one in this case)

Then connect the persistence provider to the WorkflowApplication:

```
    InstanceStore persistanceStore = new 

SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(_persistenceDataBaseConnection);

_workflowApplication.InstanceStore = persistanceStore;
```

Where _persistenceDataBaseConnection is the connection string to your SQL instence.

Now, when you run the workflow (`_workflowApplication.Run();`) the persistence store is ready for use.

It will persist the workflow when you tell it to (with a Persist activity) or when the workflow waits/delays (if you set the callback delegate: for example

`_workflowApplication.PersistableIdle = WorkflowApplicationPersistableIdle;`

Where WorkflowApplicationPersistableIdle is a method you write.

You should also save the Workflow ID somewhere for use when loading a persisted workflow ( see below)

```
WorkFlowID = _workflowApplication.Id.ToString();
```

There are a number of other features but those are the basics.

To load the workflow from the Persistence store:

Make a workflowApplication of the same type:

```
    _workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new International(), inParams);
```

and then Load it using the ID of the persisted workflow

```
_workflowApplication.Load(_workflowID);
```